# CherryPy URL Mapping not working

Tags: python, url, cherrypy, url-mapping

I am trying to get the URL mapping to work, but so far have not been able to. I'm attaching the config.conf, global.conf and server.py files, please help.

I have read the CherryPy documentation on dispatch, but I just can't catch where I might be doing the wrong thing. I'm a newbie at CherryPy.

I get the following error:

```
404 Not Found

The path '/titles.html' was not found.
In addition, the custom error page failed: 
ValueError: unsupported format character '"' (0x22) at index 1916

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/fbenavides/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/home/dev/fbenavides/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/fbenavides/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 386, in __call__
    raise self
NotFound: (404, "The path '/titles.html' was not found.")
Powered by CherryPy 3.2.4
```

global.conf

```
[global]
tools.encode.on:         True
tools.encode.encoding:   'utf-8'
tools.decode.on:         True
tools.trailing_slash.on: True
tools.staticdir.root:    server.HTTP_ROOT

log.screen:      True
log.error_file:  server.HTTP_ROOT + '/log/errors'
log.access_file: server.HTTP_ROOT + '/log/access'

server.socket_host: '0.0.0.0'
server.socket_port: 8080

error_page.404:  server.HTTP_ROOT + '/templates/404.html'
error_page.500:  server.HTTP_ROOT + '/templates/500.html'
```

config.conf

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.on:    True
tools.staticdir.debug: True
tools.staticdir.dir:   ''

[/img]
tools.staticdir.on:    True
tools.staticdir.debug: True
tools.staticdir.dir:   'img'

[/css]
tools.staticdir.on:    True
tools.staticdir.debug: True
tools.staticdir.dir:   'css'

[js]
tools.staticdir.on:    True
tools.staticdir.debug: True
tools.staticdir.dir:   'js'

[templates]
tools.staticdir.on:    True
tools.staticdir.debug: True
tools.staticdir.dir:   'templates'
```

server.py

```
# encode: utf-8
import os
import cherrypy
from datetime import date
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

HTTP_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
env       = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(HTTP_ROOT,'templates')))

conf = os.path.join(HTTP_ROOT,'config.conf')
glob = os.path.join(HTTP_ROOT,'global.conf')

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        tmpl = env.get_template('index.html')
        return tmpl.render(title='CherryPy - Pythonic WSGI OO HTTP WEB Framework')

@cherrypy.expose
def titles(self):
    today = date.today()
    tmpl = env.get_template('titles.html')
    return tmpl.render(launch1=(date(2014,2,18)-today).days)


root = Root()
root.titles = titles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update(glob)
    cherrypy.tree.mount(root, "/", config=conf)
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What is the actual behavior that is happening now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handle for titles would be just that.

```
http://localhost/titles
```

No need for the .html.  That's only relevant to the phyical path to your templating system.
However if you really do what to reference:

```
http://localhost/titles.html
```

then change your handle to this...

```
@cherrypy.expose
def titles_html(self):
    today = date.today()
    tmpl = env.get_template('titles.html')
    return tmpl.render(launch1=(date(2014,2,18)-today).days)
```

http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/concepts/dispatching.html#special-characters

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're welcome. If my response answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer - thanks!